# What does "dangling off turrets" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It takes me a while trying to understand **"dangling off"** as well as **"turrets"** in the following context, have looked up all the meanings of turret in dictionary but none makes any sense here in the context:

the context has been edited and here I have given all about bees in this book...as the "to dangling off turrets waving butterfly nets" part is just after a DASH, doesn't this mean it's still talking about how to get rid of bees? I was supposing that  they were waving butterfly nets to avoid bees...thus was stuck by "dangling off turrets"....now maybe they are   just the description of other images..?

> pages 122–123  LILY COLE IN EARTHQUAKE-DAMAGED ROOM
>
> WHADWAN, GUJARAT, INDIA, 2005
>
> British Vogue
>
> ‘We were in the most amazing abandoned palace with giant rooms shaken
>   by the huge earthquake four years previously’, recalls Lily, ‘it had
>   never been restored and so existed eerily like some large film-set or
>   a haunted house Disneyland attraction. What an adventure those ten
>   days in India were: from getting locked into rooms to avoid the
>   thousands of stinging bees that swarmed at midday – it was each for
>   himself fighting for hats, skirts and so on to hide under – to
>   **dangling off turrets** waving butterfly nets ...’
>
> Ragi Dholakia:‘One particularly hot March whilst shooting in a 13th
>   century palace I noticed a few hornets in the courtyard outside. As
>   the morning progressed it got worse and soon the team’s way in and out
>   was buzzing with hundreds of giant hornets. Members of the crew
>   started to be stung. We shut the doors and windows in the hope the
>   swarm would disperse. It didn’t. After being trapped in the room for
>   an hour the angry insects started to infiltrate the room. We resorted
>   to lighting newspaper to smoke towels which covered our heads and
>   making a speedy dash for it.’

From [Pictures by Tim Walker](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Pictures.html?id=7SI_RvE5WJYC)

Comment: The primary definitions for "dangling" and "turret" seem to make sense to me in this context:  what is it about them that seems wrong to you?

Comment: “dangling off” here is probably a bit of hyperbole, but all the words have their usual meaning.  Probably more literally described as “leaning dangerously far over the side of a turret with our butterfly nets in our outstretched hands”

Comment: You may have missed the underlying ... from getting locked into rooms to dangling off turrets ...

Comment: Not sure that dangling and leaning over are the same thing. I agree it is hyperbole: they are hanging off the turret (by a rope?)....

Comment: I can't find a shot with actual dangling, but [this page](http://www.porcelainista.net/?p=11698) has a Walker image of Lily Cole in an Indian turret (and another of her with a butterfly net), and it's very easy to imagine her leaning out of or hanging off of the turret. And that palace has lots of similar turrets.

Comment: We're missing a lot of context.  If these people were lepidopterists it would all make perfect sense.

Comment: (Recommending that the question be closed unless OP provides more context.)

Comment: @HotLicks I think StoneyB's comment is on point. Tim Walker is a photographer and [his photos](http://www.porcelainista.net/?p=11698) show *towers/turrets* and *nets* to catch honeybees.

Comment: It could mean rappelling down the turret with a butterfly net in one hand.   https://www.google.com/search?q=rappelling&biw=1094&bih=569&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjCmab9lYDMAhVBKCYKHRnbDskQsAQIGw

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really is unclear what the writer is saying.  The OP is right to be perplexed.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but as the "to dangling off turrets waving butterfly nets" part is just after a DASH, doesn't this mean it's still talking about how to get rid of bees? I was supposing that  they were waving butterfly nets to avoid bees...thus was stuck by "dangling off turrets"....now maybe they are   just the description of other images..???

Comment: @Veronica I see you've made a lot of improvement to the question. I vote to reopen it. :)

Comment: I won't address the "dangling off turrets" part specifically, since it seems to have been adequately handled, but rather try to illuminate the overall meaning of the sentence.  The author is saying "What an adventure those ten days in India were;" *we had experiences **ranging "from*** getting locked into rooms … ***to*** dangling off turrets …"  In case it's not clear, I'm saying that "dangling off turrets" really has nothing to do with the bees.  Compare to "What a day I had: from eating popcorn at the ball game to dining at a fine restaurant."

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to imagine someone leaning precariously from a turret with a butterfly net to try to capture some wayward lepidopteran.  One might lean far enough out to exaggeratingly refer to it as "dangling".  Here's the turret in my imagination.  Think of leaning out from one of the castellations for this purpose:

[image]

Comment: "Here's the turret in my imagination."  I've had lots of things in my imagination, but never a turret.  Your brain must be one wild place!

Comment: Oh, it is, @HotLicks, it is!  :-)

Comment: A turret's a place where you can really let your hair down!